# What privileges and responsibilities did Tom Paris lose when he was reduced to ensign?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

When Tom got busted to ensign, he would have lost things like being able to give orders to ensigns, for instance. Did he lose anything else? What was the benefit of him being a lieutenant that he did not get when he was an ensign?

Comment: He may have had to share a room

Comment: He would lose Time in Grade.... For instance you need to be an Ensign for 2 years before you can get promoted to Lieutenant JG.  Then 3 years as Lt JG before able to be promoted to Lieutenant. The say 4 years as Lieutenant before you could be promoted to LT Commander. (Years are examples, I don't know actually values. Assumes no early  Promotions for Meritorious Service or Special circumstances or duties)  SO Assuming Paris had been a LT for 2 years before demotion, It would take using the above numbers, 7 years with on time promotions to get back to where he Had been Time in Grade wise.

Comment: Possibly holodeck time or replicator rations? Choice of shifts? I don't think it's discussed in main canon, might br something in extended universe.

Comment: @Tronman I agree that Tom's specific situation wasn't discussed, but probably the general privileges of Lt vs. Ensign would be, no?

Comment: @Tronman - "Possibly holodeck time or replicator rations?" - I would tend to think not, unless it was mentioned in the series. It would seem very archaic/unfair if lower ranks got lower rations or holodeck time, especially given the predicament the ship is in...